# SQL as in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I Have problem, I Use codeigniter. I Have a long sql, and I will use it to my codeigniter. My database.php is:

```
...
$db = 'simpeg';
..
```

I will apply this sql into code igniter.
My long SQL is:
...

```
"SELECT
            thsms,
            kd_dosen,
            nama,

            fakultas_ekonomi,
            fakultas_hukum,
            fakultas_teknik_sipil_dan_perencanaan,
            fakultas_teknologi_industri,

            fakultas_mipa,
            fakultas_iai,
            fakultas_psikologi_dan_ilmu_sosial_budaya,
            fakultas_kedokteran,
            fakultas_d3k,
            fakultas_d3fe,
            fakultas_PM,

            fakultas_ekonomi + fakultas_hukum + fakultas_teknik_sipil_dan_perencanaan + fakultas_teknologi_industri + fakultas_mipa + fakultas_iai + fakultas_psikologi_dan_ilmu_sosial_budaya + fakultas_kedokteran + fakultas_d3k
            AS total_durasi

        FROM (
            SELECT
                thsms,
                kd_dosen,
                nama,

                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FE', sks,0)) AS fakultas_ekonomi,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FH', sks,0)) AS fakultas_hukum,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FTI', sks,0)) AS fakultas_teknologi_industri,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FTSP', sks,0)) AS fakultas_teknik_sipil_dan_perencanaan,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'MIPA', sks,0)) AS fakultas_mipa,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FK', sks,0)) AS fakultas_kedokteran,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FPSB', sks,0)) AS fakultas_psikologi_dan_ilmu_sosial_budaya,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'FIAI', sks, 0)) AS fakultas_iai,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'D3K', sks, 0)) AS fakultas_d3k,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'D3FE', sks, 0)) AS fakultas_d3fe,
                SUM(IF(fakultas = 'PM', sks, 0)) AS fakultas_PM

                FROM
                sks_mengajar
            WHERE thsms = '".$tahun_akademik_berlaku."' AND nama NOT LIKE '%DOSEN%' AND nama NOT LIKE '%ASS.%' 
            GROUP BY nama
        ) AS temp_table"
...
```

I Need this long sql change to short SQL in Codeigniter.
like this:

```
$this->db-> .....
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what you need?? unclear what you're asking

Comment: this is all documented here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class

Comment: Why do you want to convert it? As @MrCarrot points out, you can use it for parameter passing, but the big benefit of the query builder library is for simpler, and usually dynamic queries. If your query works, I wouldn't try to recreate it in PHP for it to be converted back again...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do complex sub queries using CodeIgniter's Query Builder.

The best you're going to get is:

```
$sql = "SELECT thsms, kd_dosen, nama... WHERE thsms = ? AND..."

$params = array($tahun_akademik_berlaku);

$query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);
```